# Where should I start to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

If $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=2$$
then calculate
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x+14)-3147f(x+1)}{f(x+2)+f(x)}$$

Where should I start to solve this problem? This is not a homework. Only I need a hint.

Comment: Divide by $f(x) $ on both numerator and denominator. .

Comment: Wait how is that limit equal to two? You will then get $\frac{2^{14}-2*3147}{2^2+1}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{f(x+14)-3147f(x+1)}{f(x+2)+f(x)}=\frac{\frac{f(x+14)}{f(x+13)}\cdot\frac{f(x+13)}{f(x+12)}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{f(x+2)}{f(x+1)}-3147}{\frac{f(x+2)}{f(x+1)}+\frac{f(x)}{f(x+1)}}$

Comment: Is this question valid and is my answer correct? I am having trouble as how can that limit be two??

Comment: @KingTut If $f(x)=2^x$, then the given limit is $2$. And I think my answer is essentially the same as what you gave in your comments to OP.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!